# SQL Query, Selecting 1 Element, with highest COUNT element B, and lowest VALUE Element C

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm quite stuck with the following question:

Table "SUPPLIER": 1004 distinct articles, with 21 different Suppliers (so many articles have the same supplier, but the same article never has more than 1 supplier)

Table "ARTICLE": 1004 Articles, Price of each article, Kind of article(Clothing,Food etc).
So each distinct article has a distinct price, but certain groups of articles belong to 1 kind.

Example: Article number 32 (Men shoe size 40), 236 (women shoe size 40), 54 (Kid shoe size 20) all have "SHOE" at the Column "KIND".

QUESTION:
Ill split the question into 2 parts.

1. Select the KIND of articles, where the AMOUNT of suppliers of this KIND of articles is HIGHEST.
2. Of this group, select the ARTICLE with the lowest price.

In the end, the answer is supposed to be: ARTICLE, PRICE, SUPPLIER. (In other words, the Article which belongs to the KIND of articles that has the highest amount of suppliers, and has the lowest price).

I only got this so far after a lot of pondering..

```
SELECT 
    article.art, article.price, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT supplier.sup)
FROM article, supplier
WHERE article.art = supplier.art
GROUP BY artikel.art
```

I expected this to show me how many suppliers each article had, but it doesnt.
I'm sure you have to use things like:

`HAVING MIN(price)`

or

`ORDER BY article.price ASC AND COUNT(DISTINCT supplier.sup) DESC`

I've tried every combination of code I deem possible but I cannot find the answer. Is anyone here able to?

Comment: amount of suppliers? I didn't get this. can you elaborate. it would be a good idea to list few rows of your tables and construct a result table which you want to see. that way we can understand easily.

Comment: Isn't the price something that is defined by the supplier? I am a little bit surprised to find that in the article table.

Comment: Lowest priced article in what group? Do you simply mean the lowest priced article?

Comment: Sorry ill elaborate better, editing post :)

Comment: There, Hope it's better understandable. Thanks for the quick replies!

Comment: What column designates the kind of article?

Comment: The kind of article is designated by article.kind

Comment: What about ties? What if more than one article kind has the most suppliers?

Comment: In case of a tie, the group of Kind of articles with the article with the lowest price is supposed to be selected.

Comment: If that is also a tie, then nevermind, then the makers of this assignment shouldve specified better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT
    article.art, article.price, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT supplier.sup)
FROM article LEFT OUTER JOIN supplier ON article.art = supplier.art
ORDER BY artikel.price ASC 
LIMIT 0,1
GROUP BY artikel.art
```